# r what filename for saving gganimate file

Tags: r, ggplot2, ffmpeg

The following two lines of code, taken from this [script](https://github.com/openmodelingfoundation/landuse/blob/master/R/importLUH2Data.R), do what I think they should; that is, use a previously generated ggplot file - gganim - create an animation in Rstudio's viewer (the first line) and save the last animation to the graphics directory on my mac (the second line). But my mac thinks this is a txt file. I've tried adding .mpeg, mp4, etc. to the file name without any success. Seems like one of this problems I'll do a Homer Simpson on after someone points out the solution.

```
gganimate::animate(gganim, nframes = length(yearsToDisplay), fps = 1, renderer = ffmpeg_renderer())
gganimate::anim_save("animateOutput", animation = last_animation(), path = "graphics")
```

Comment: Maybe it's `.gif`?

Comment: Try adding in the ".mp4" and removing the `path="graphics"`  so it saves to your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I discovered that the following modifications to the two lines work; that is, I explicitly specify the file format in the ffmpeg_render function and in the anim_save file name

```
gganimate::animate(gganim, format = "mp4", nframes = length(yearsToDisplay), fps = 1, renderer = ffmpeg_renderer(format = "mp4"))
gganimate::anim_save("animateOutput.mp4", animation = last_animation(), path = "graphics")
```